# SQL uniqueidentifier bulk data migration

Tags: sql

I have encountered a problem with this query:

```sql
    DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier
    SET @id = NEWID()
    insert into Records ([Id],Ref1,Ref2,Name1,Date1) values
    (@id,'a','b','c',GETDATE()),
    (@id,'a','b','c',GETDATE()),
    (@id,'a','b','c',GETDATE()),
    (@id,'a','b','c',GETDATE()),
```

I have 200 data rows to input; I try to bulk insert using ['] after each row, but I get an error message `You must declare @id uniqueidentifier`.

How can I solve this for multiple data rows migration for insertion?

thanks again

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: And mention it in your question; bonus for including the software version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE.  In SQL Server, this looks like:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n < 200
     )
insert into Records ([Id],Ref1,Ref2,Name1,Date1)
    select @id, 'a', 'b', 'c', GETDATE()
    from n
    with option (maxrecursion 0);
```